# Hover on CSS menu only affects part of element?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've made a css dropdown menu and I want each dropdown option to have a blue background when it is hovered on. However when I try this the background for the option will only be blue when the top half of it is hovered on. Here it is on jsfiddle. If you hover your mouse on the "products" option and then put the mouse under "plates" but above the gray horizontal line the background won't be blue. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/hDWuJ/1/

HTML (Note this is a segment of my web page and so it does not have valid syntax)

```
<h1 id="title">Sample Text</h1>
<div id="HorzLineDiv"><hr></div>    
<div id="MenuCenter">
<nav id="Menu" class="MenuBar">
    <ul id="drop-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products <span id="arrowDown">&#9660</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Children's Stuff</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Plates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top Sellers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services <span id="arrowDown">&#9660</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Wash 'n' Fold</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blanket Making</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Wedding Dress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

#title
{
    text-align: center;
    color: #07a8ca;
    font-size:60pt;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #888888;
}

h1
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

hr 
{
    height: 3px;
    color: #07a8ca;
    background: #07a8ca;
    font-size: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#HorzLineDiv
{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2% 0% 3% 0%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}

#Menu
{
    width:100%;
}

#drop-nav
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
}

ul 
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}

ul li 
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 12px 50px 8px 50px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border-left: 3px solid #07a8ca;
}

ul li:first-child
{
    border-left: 0px; 
}

li ul 
{
    display: none;
}

ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    color: #000;
    font: 25px/1.1em "Kelly Slab","serif";
    transition: color 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease 0s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease 0s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease 0s; /* Opera */
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #FF4D4D;
}

li:hover ul 
{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li 
{
    float: none;
}

li:hover a 
{
    margin:0;
}

li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #21e8fa;
}

#drop-nav li ul li 
{
   border-top: 0px; 
   border-left: 0px;
}

#drop-nav ul li a
{
    border-top: 3px solid #888;
    padding: 13px 0px 13px 0px;
    margin: -10px -8px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: none;
    position:relative;
    top: 13px;
    color: #000;
}

#drop-nav ul
{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
}

a
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#arrowDown
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    vertical-align:text-bottom
}
```

Comment: The -ve margins and the strangely positioned `<li>`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in your margins and padding, but this can be worked around by changing your `ul li` to `display: block;` instead of `display: inline;`.

Of course, this isn't a direct fix to the issue, and there still is an area at the bottom that doesn't work on hover, but it is much smaller than before. The proper way to go about fixing this is fixing your margins and padding.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/hDWuJ/3/)

**UPDATE**

Reading deeper into your code, I found the actual problem. It is not in margins or padding as I originally thought, but is a `top` property of 13px defined in `#drop-nav ul li a`. That top of 13px was creating a blank, inactive space in your list.

Get rid of that piece and it is working fine: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/hDWuJ/6/)